# Oracle Database Memory Issue

Tags: oracle

> Out of Memory Error

ORA -04030: Out Of Process Memory When Trying to allocate 64528 byte(Short subheap, sort key)

[image]

Comment: Please don't paste images, use formatted text. Usually Ctrl+C works also on error dialogs.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking this is an actual out of memory error on the Oracle server typically caused by a too small pga.
The most likely resolution (depending on your server version) in to increase the [PGA_AGGREGATE_TARGET](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-DEBBD3F7-9F6D-4AC8-952C-0E0B2E62312D.htm#REFRN10165) configuration setting.